# Scheduling text messages

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I'm trying to make an android application that sends pre-written messages on a certain date, the date that the user enters.More like an app that sends birthday messages automatically.My doubt is, what the application still work if the app is not open for days and if it does how can I do it.Thank You. I also looked at similar question but it did not clear my doubt.

Comment: The question is how you want your app to behave? send automatic messages or reminder user that need to send message. when you say message you mean SMS?

Comment: I want to send automatic SMS

Comment: You already added the answer in Tags . Its `AlarmManager`. So its 365 days in a year you can have pre-written text in database for each day or you can fetch them from some data source as per need . When you say message i am assuming a notification . And yeah `AlarmManger` will work if your app is not running . have a deep look at the documentation (including doze and standby mode).

Comment: you can use alarm manger or work manager or job scheduler for this BUT remember that google put very strong restrictions fro all SMS and PHONE related permission and to be able to publish app which contains one of those permission you must send special request to google and explain why you need this permission.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to use AlarmManager for scheduling actions 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager

You can send sms using

SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);